# External Product on K-group

Tags: homology-cohomology, operator-algebras, k-theory

I am working on Prop 4.8.3 of Higson & Roe's *Analytic K-Homology* recently. It asks me to verify that for unital C*-Algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, if $u$ is a unitary of $\mathcal{A}$ and $p$ is a projection of $\mathcal{B}$, then the external product can be presented by

$\times : K_1(\mathcal{A})\times K_0(\mathcal{B})\to K_1(\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}),\quad [u]\times[p]\mapsto[u\otimes p+1\otimes(1-p)]$

with the tensor product being the minimal tensor product.

I tried to use the isomorphism

$K_1(\mathcal{A})\times K_0(\mathcal{B})\cong K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{A})\times K_0(\mathcal{B})\to K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})\cong K_1(\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})$

since we already know the external product between $K_0$ groups are simply $[p]\times[q]=[p\otimes q]$. But I was stuck figuring out how $[u]\in K_1(\mathcal{A})$ corresponds to the element in $K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{A})$.

Any help will be sincerely grateful!

Comment: Please do not use bold-faced, All-caps, in color, and drop the +1, which directly violates commenting guidelines, @Albert.

Comment: Ouch. I basically violated every rule of commenting in one line. Why are colors forbidden btw ?